# Is there a way to save a class's this pointer into a member shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, this-pointer, class-template

I have a structure like this:

**Foo.h**

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
     // Public For Now While Constructing Class
     std::shared_ptr<T> m_p256[256];

private:
    static unsigned m_elementCount;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo<T>>> m_foos;

public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void add( T object );
}; // Foo
```

**Foo.inl**

```
template<class T>
unsigned Foo<T>::m_elementCount = 0;

template<class T>
Foo<T>::Foo() :
m_p256{ nullptr } {
} // Foo

template<class T>
Foo<T>::~Foo() {
} // ~Foo 

template<class T>
void Foo<T>::add( T obj ) {
   m_elementCount++;

   if ( m_elementCount == 256 ) {
       // Save Current Instance To Our Vector       
       // Here Is Where I've Tried Several Things And Where I'm Currently Stuck

       m_foos.push_back( a shared_ptr of this instance );

       // Reset Element Count
       m_elementCount = 0;
       Foo<T>* fooPtr = new Foo<T>();
       fooPtr->add( obj );

   } else {
       std::shared_ptr<T> pT( new T( obj ) );
       m_p256[m_elementCount-1] = pT;
   }

} // add
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is pass any arbitrary object of the same type using the add function. Once the element count reaches 256 elements and the internal array of smart pointers of that type passed in is filled I want to save the current instance of this class's instantiated object and push it into the vector and the next object being passed in belongs to the new or next instance that is created, however all later instances are still a part of the original object. So as each array of 256 is filled, it will act like a linked list so to speak but it is more of a chaining effect. I'm just stuck at saving the current state of this instance.

Comment: `push_back(this)` not compiling? See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) keyword.

Comment: It *almost* seems like you're looking for a way to use [std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this). Note the shared pointer peeled out of that scenario isn't just manufactured out of thin air. The object on which it is based must actually be a dynamic `std::shared_ptr` construct, but it looks like it may fit your situation, so worth the read.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmm; I added to my class for it to be publicly derived from std::shared_from_this. my constructor is empty and only initializes variables, and after I make sure that the arrays are filled within my add function is when and where I tried to either create a share_ptr using the assignment operator setting it equal to shared_from_this(). I am able to compile and build, but when I run the program I'm getting chrashes, about weak_ptr being null coming from the memory module. Seems like I'm getting seg faults and unhandled execptions.

Comment: I've used shared_ptr before in many other class where they contain a single or a vector of shared pointers of other classes with no problem. This is the first time I've used one in this context, where my class on its initial instantiation will hold nested versions of itself. So in a sense this template class is recursive in nature as long as there are more elements to be stored than the internal container. I could deviate and leave this class the way it is and create a wrapper class to manage it, but I thought that it might be a little too much over head and figured I could self contain...

Comment: (...continued) Here I thought using smart pointers was better and easier for being less prone to memory leaks, dangling pointers, error in pointer arithmetic etc. And now I'm at a fork in the road, and don't know which way to go. I'd prefer to keep the pointers self contained since it is still the same object. Maybe I could restructure it a little. Maybe I could contain my array in a self contained structure within my class and when the array is full, I can just push that array into my vector, since my array will be holding shared pointers of the same arbitrary type.

Comment: Make sure you derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this` (you mentioned `std::shared_from_this`, hopefully a typo) as the documentation prescribes. Secondly, and as the documentation states, this only works for object instances that *themselves* are in-fact already being managed by a *preexisting* `std::shared_ptr<T>`. That part is critical. The whole point of `std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this()` is to provide you a way of participating in sharing that preexisting `std::shared_ptr<>`within your member functions without having to have someone hand it to you via formal parameter.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes it was a typo ... I was inheriting from std::enable_shared_from_this and I was using shared_from_this to try and set the pointer.

Comment: And your *instance* of the object who's member you're doing this from is itself managed by a `std::shared_ptr`, right ? It has to be, or it won't work. You can't for example have `Obj *p = new Obj; p->someMember();` and have `someMember()` invoke `shared_from_this`. You *can*, however, do `auto sp = std::make_shared<Obj>(); sp->someMember();`

Comment: @WhozCraig I was trying to do that within my class, but to no avail it wouldn't work. Now if you're asking if I have the instance of this class as a shared pointer from somewhere else such as in main, then no, I have just a normal instance instantiated.

Comment: I might go a different direction anyway; instead of trying to make multiple new instances, I think I might just wrap my array[256] within a struct contained in the class, then just hold a vector of them once that array is full.